# Keystrokes going to IntelliJ instead of terminal in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I often startup vi in a terminal in IntelliJ. When I press shortcut keys like 'Ctrl + N' etc. IntelliJ picks it up as shortcut keys and open up a dialog etc. Anyway to get around this?